# rpy2 ggplot2 does not plot a window in PyCharm

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, pycharm, rpy2

I am running

```
import pandas as pd

import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2
import rpy2.robjects as ro

from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')

measurements = pd.DataFrame({'time': [0,1], 'value': [2,3]})

gp = ggplot2.ggplot(measurements)
pp = gp + \
        ggplot2.aes_string(x='time', y='value') + \
        ggplot2.geom_line()
pp.plot()
```

but no window opens when I run this in a Python Console of PyCharm 2019.2.3, while it works if I run it in a Python Console in the terminal (Linux Kubuntu 14.4).

I am using the following conda environment in the background

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
ca-certificates           2019.9.11            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.9.11                py37_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.6               he372182_0    conda-forge
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_3    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.5             he1b5a44_1004    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            he4413a7_1000    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.0               he983fc9_1    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          hc5be6a0_1002    conda-forge
glib                      2.58.3            h6f030ca_1002    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.14.5               h0935bb2_0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.14.5               h36ae1b5_0    conda-forge
icu                       58.2              hf484d3e_1000    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        0.23                     pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2019.4                      243  
jinja2                    2.10.3                   pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9c                h14c3975_1001    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37hc9558a2_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libiconv                  1.15              h516909a_1005    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               hed695b0_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libuuid                   2.32.1            h14c3975_1000    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.9                h13577e0_2    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37h5429711_0  
mizani                    0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.4                      243  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37hd6b4f25_0  
more-itertools            7.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
numpy                     1.17.2           py37haad9e8e_0  
numpy-base                1.17.2           py37hde5b4d6_0  
openssl                   1.1.1c               h516909a_0    conda-forge
packaging                 19.2                     pypi_0    pypi
palettable                3.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.25.2           py37he6710b0_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.43                 he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0  
plotnine                  0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pluggy                    0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pthread-stubs             0.4               h14c3975_1001    conda-forge
py                        1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.19                     pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37hcca6a23_4    conda-forge
pytest                    5.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.4                h265db76_1  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h52cfd70_2    conda-forge
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
rpy2                      3.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h7c811a0_0  
setuptools                41.4.0                   py37_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sip                       4.19.8           py37hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0  
sqlite                    3.30.1               h7b6447c_0  
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37hc1659b7_1    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h516909a_0    conda-forge
tzlocal                   2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0  
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h14c3975_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h516909a_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zipp                      0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your pycharm running a local python process ? If not, you might have to set `DISPLAY` accordingly:
   [Configuring macOS PyCharm for X11 Forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765754/configuring-macos-pycharm-for-x11-forwarding)
2. If everything is local, the use of conda suggests to ask how did you install R and pycharm (and do you have more than one installation of R). This could explain a difference in behavior between the two.

Additional note: If using R interactive plot you might find useful to take care of R's event loop: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/interactive.html#r-event-loop

Comment: 1. Do you mean by "if not" that I run it on a server? I do not - everything is on my notebook.

Comment: 2. I am using the commands I displayed in my question. I don't think this is what you mean by interactive, is it?

Comment: In 1/ I am asking about whether the python process evaluating your code / running rpy2 is local (your notebook) or is running on a remote machine. Pycharm allows to have the IDE running locally (all the UI you are using to interact with your code) while the process can be remote.

Comment: 2/ is only an additional comment about what might be useful for you to know once you manage to solve the issue described in the question.

Comment: 1) Everything is local, yes. 2) My regular R installation is separate and has nothing to do with the question. The R installation I am using here is within my conda environment which I use from PyCharm. When I activate this conda environment from a terminal (not PyCharm) and run my command, I am using that conda-R (not the regular other R installation). Is this answering your questions?

Comment: I believe that rpy2 will bind to *a* R library on your system, and I have seen that it was not always the one a user thought it was. The process of asking questions is to try guess what might be happening, and what has to do with the issue. Since the R `rpy2` binds to is different between your Pycharm and your command line setup, I would encourage you to investigate whether one was compiled with X11 support while the other was not.

Comment: Can you give a "step by step" description on how I can do the investigation? I have not idea how to approach this.